# How to Automatically Recover Tomcat From Crashes

Tags: java, tomcat, cron, redhat

My tomcat crashes occasionally . SO I want to run a scheduler so that at the time of crash , tomcat restart automatically . Here is my logic :

```
every few minutes {
  check tomcat status;

  if (status is "not running") {
    start tomcat;
  }
}
```

I am following [this lesson](https://dzone.com/articles/how-automatically-recover) . But I do not have "/etc/init.d/tomcat" file . I also do not have this file , "$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/tomcat.pid" . SO I cant follow the above tutorial .

I have searched a lot in the internet but do not have single in this topic . Please help me so that I can write a script that automatically start tomcat  at the time of crashes . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Have you thought about hosting in the cloud (e.g. AWS, Azure, etc.)?  I think these environments have the ability so spin up a new Tomcat should one of your nodes go down.  This might be faster for you rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I cant deploy my server in cloud right now.  Any alternatives?

Comment: _I do not have "/etc/init.d/tomcat" file_.  Which Redhat version is yours (cat /etc/*release*) ?

Comment: _I also do not have this file_ Check if you have any setenv.sh file (which is supposed to contain all your environment variables), and look in all other files if the TOMCAT_PID is defined (in catalina.sh, tomcat.sh..) . If missing, you can create one setenv.sh in your bin dir, such as TOMCAT_PID=$CATALINA_HOME/logs/tomcat.pid

Comment: In all case, it is better to investigate why Tomcat is stopping itself. Memory too small ? Anything interesting in the catalina.out log file ?